# how to travel through the array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, key

i am having one key list
for example

```
  $key_list=array("list"=>array("task","duration"));

function array_key_fun($key_list,$test_input){
    //(is_array($test_input)){
return    array_map('myfunction',$test_input,$key_list);
    //}
}


//$va=array_map("myfunction",$test_input);
//print_r(array_key_fun($key_list,$test_input));

function myfunction($arr)
{
    if(is_array($arr))
        {

        $get_array=    get_childs($arr);
            return $get_array;
        }
 }
function get_childs($arr){

                    $newarr=array();
                    $newarr_en='';
                                    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)    
                        {    

                        if(is_array($value)){
                              $newarr[$key]=get_childs($value);

                        }else{

                            if (in_array($key,$key_list)) //here im facing the problem with key_list
                                      {
                                        ..............
                                      }
                                     else
                                     {
                                        ...............
                                     }

                            }

                        }
           return $newarr;



    }
```

Comment: Please add: you error. how you call function `abc()`. What `$a` is.

Comment: i am getting undefined variable $key_list in fun.....

Comment: but im using tat $arr as $key=>$value .........in get_childs($value,$key_list) i declared...its giving...Notice: Undefined variable: key_list in F:\wamp\www\ext-3.3.0\myexamples\encode examples\saved_array_map_new.php on line 157.error

Answer (score 2):

Either pass in function or declare as global

```
function abc($a,$key_list){
```

OR

```
function abc($a){
  global $key_list;
  //rest of code
```

EDIT:

When you pass the array as parameter of function you have to pass the value in call as well

when you call this function this should be

```
//array should be declared before calling function 
  $key_list=array("list"=>array("task","duration")); 
  abc($a,$key_list); //pass this array
```

Comment: but $key_list is outside the fun.......i need to check whether the key is present in tat array so tat i can do next part.........

Comment: i tried ur way,passed in fun but still getting undefined variable error

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: key_list in F:\wamp\www\ext-3.3.0\myexamples\encode examples\saved_array_map_new.php on line 150

Comment: @0001: Can you show me how you are calling this function I have given example in my answer?

Comment: @0001: hummm Could you try this `function get_childs($arr){ global $key_list;`

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

```
array_walk
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You have to bring the variable into scope, within your code you have `.........` if you replace that with `global $key_list` this will allow the function to Read / Write to that stack.